# rest api are too slow

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm buildin rest apis for mobile app and when call the api it takes about 20 to 30 second to responds.

I'm in developer mode and disabled the cache.

> requirements are satisfied:
>
> - php version is 7.0.8
> - apache version is 2.4

I'm running on `xampp` with `phpmyadmin` database
Is that because of my implementation of the api or there is other reasons?

Comment: What cache did you disable?

Comment: Can you please try after enabling the cache? if you properly precompile static files, enable all caches and setup Varnish speed as 10x times faster.
you have to start from here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bk-config-guide.html